# Git GUI client with sparse-checkout and partial-clone support?

Tags: windows, git

We are considering migrating from SVN to Git.

We have one SVN repo specific to our external components (ex: libraries not available as packages, binary assets, etc.).

The rule is to only add new stuff to this repo but not remove or modify existing files in order to not break client codes.

Typical file tree on the SVN server is:

```
lib1/
     v2021/ # added in 2021
     v2022/ # added in 2022
lib2/
     v1.0/
     v2.0/
```

This SVN repo is over 100 Gb in size so the custom is to either only [checkout what we need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1668279) using Tortoise SVN, or do multiple checkouts of some sub directories, at the matching location.

Example using a single (sparse) checkout on a developer computer:

```
/externals/ # this is the only SVN checkout (sparse)
           lib1/
                v2022/
           lib2/
                v2.0/
```

Example using multiple checkouts on a developer computer:

```
/externals/ # a regular directory (unknown to SVN)
           lib1/ # a regular directory
                v2022/ # this is a SVN checkout (not sparse)
           lib2/ # a regular directory
                v2.0/ # this is another SVN checkout (not sparse)
```

The equivalent with Git could be to have a single repository that we [sparse checkout](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout). Doing multiple clones with different roots is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097530/git-sparse-checkout-without-leading-directories) afaik (in a sparse checkout the clone's root is the usual one).

I think that [partial clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/partial-clone) would also be needed to avoid downloading everything.

Therefore, I am looking for a Git GUI client that would allow sparse checkout and partial clone, on Windows.